# DataGrid DataGridComboBoxColumn lose its value after collapsing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a `GridView` whith `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, it works fine the first time, but when set the column `visibility` to `collapsed`, and then return the `visibility` to `visible` again, the column lose its value. but the property which is bounded to it still has the correct value.

when refresh the DataContext all the values gets binded correctly.

I add a test Converter, and noticed that when collapsing the column, the call back method is fired, and the value is null.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding DbId}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                        SelectedValuePath="Id"
                        Visibility="Visible">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding TestList}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding TestList}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on TestList so that the UI will reflect the change.

Comment: already implemented and working fine, updating the datacontext gets all the values updated correctly.

Comment: can you post more code details? converter i mean

Comment: the converter does not have any logic, it just to check the values. when collapsing the column, the convert back method is called, and the value is null.

Comment: return the same visibility which you are returning in convert method.

Comment: the problem is with the selected value, not the visibility, it's not bounding correctly after setting the column from collapsed to visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. You could work around it by handling the `Loaded` event for the `ComboBox` in the `CellTemplate` and re-set the `SelectedValue` property:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding TestList}"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="OnLoaded" />
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

---

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
    dynamic dataObject = cmb.DataContext;
    cmb.SelectedValue = dataObject.DbId;
}
```

Another solution would be to replace the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. You then want to bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to a `Db` property of your data object to be able to display the `Name` property of the `Db` object in the `CellTemplate`.

Comment: on Loaded I just called the DataContext and raised OnPropertyCanged and it works fine. thanks